# Reuse Extractors?

Tags: jmeter

I've used a Module Controller to invoke a Test Fragment.  This is a great way to reuse Controllers and Samplers across multiple Thread Groups.

I have a set of about a dozen Extractors (CSS and RegEx) that I'd like to reuse for different HTTP Samplers.  (The Samplers would be different, but the Extractors I'd run against each would be the same.)

Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

- You can use scopes if it applies , see http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules
- Otherwise put you CSS expressions in Variables and use them in extractor